# ncurses dialog shows qqqq/xxxx lines instead of lines

Tags: dialog, ncurses

dialog --version --> Version: 1.0-20051107
I have two machines, both RHEL5 linux, with identical versions of dialog. 
On machine A, my dialog renders nicely.  On machine B, I get the same colors and shadows, but lines are rendered with ascii letters like this:

```
lqqqqqqqk
x       x
x       x
mqqqqqqqj
```

This problem occurs even with trivial invocations like:
    dialog --menu Main 16 60 9 1 View

Both machines have ncurses-5.5-24.20060715.
Both machines show the TERM environment variable as 'xterm'.
Both machine show locale as LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Any idea what's wrong with machine B?

Comment: this clearly relates somehow to:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820342/using-ncurses-in-a-virtual-terminal?rq=1

Comment: The [ncurses FAQ](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#no_line_drawing) might be useful.

Comment: try setting `export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1` before running dialog

Answer (score 4):

```
export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1
```

will solve your problem :)